# How can I specify which instance of ConEmu to create new console in?

Tags: conemu

I am trying to start up numerous services for a large enterprise application and put them into two distinct ConEmu instances: one for WebJobs and one for APIs. Is there some way to specify which instance of ConEmu to run a command in with **-reuse**? I'm currently having to collect together all the WebJobs, start them all with **-reuse** to get them into the initial instance, and then start a new instance **-detached** and start up the APIs with **-reuse**. It seems like **-reuse** only attaches to the last ConEmu instance I start up.

If I wanted to be able to start up additional instances of the WebJobs, is there some way to tell it to put the new tab/console in the first instance of ConEmu?